# Android - Forcing application language with configuration.locale does not change app_name in launcher

Tags: android, locale

I have the following code to force use of English as application language.

```java
Configuration configuration =
    getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration();

configuration.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;

getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(
    configuration, getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

The problem is that it works inside activities, but the `name in launcher` and `app_name on titlebar` don't change, they stay with system locale.

How can I change those names too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I change those names too?

The user can go into Settings and change their locale.

You, as a developer, can use `updateConfiguration()` to trick Android into using a different language's resources *for your own process*. You cannot affect other apps that way, and the home screen is another app.

Comment: I feel I should still be able to change the title bar, do you know if that is possible, please? It creates an incoherent user interface if that and the window contents are in different languages.

Comment: @VašekPotoček: The title bar/action bar is part of your process, and the only text that appears in the title bar is what you put there.

Comment: I am specifying the title using `android:label` in the manifest and the decoded string value seemed to be cached for recently open Activities (even though they were cleared using an Intent) and never changed if the same resource was used as for the displayed app name. (This made me think, originally, that is not affected by the overridden locale setting). At this moment I am using `System.exit(0)` to be sure that all resources will be reloaded. I'm not sure if it's a good practice but it works perfectly.

Comment: @Vašek Potoček: Thanks for your suggestion on `System.exit(0)` - I had lots of caching problems, which were solved by this dirty trick :-)

Comment: @JörgEisfeld Is there any solution better than this?

Comment: @K.Sopheak: I don't know another solution that works as reliably