# Supporting multiple Indian languages

Tags: android, localization, locale

I need to support multiple Indian languages in my application, for example hindi, marathi, oriya, etc. Is it possible to create a custom locale, or something similar, which can make this task simpler?

For example: is it possible to write hindi, texts in a `strings.xml` file, and store it in say values-hi, and then set the locale using the following code:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("hi");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
```

Can some similar functionality be achieved, as there are a lot of texts in my application.

Comment: You can achieve this using font.

Comment: Using, font I will have to do setText everytime. All indian languages have alphabets of different patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531783/android-forcing-application-language-with-configuration-locale-does-not-change) to figure out how to force a locale in your application.

Basically, do something like this:

```
Configuration configuration =
getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration();

configuration.locale = new Locale("hi); 

getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(
configuration, getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

And then, create the values-hi with your strings.xml

Follow the [list of languages](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry)

Answer (score 0):

ofcourse you can, here is how to do it in your app and let the user choose the prefered language: [How to pragmatically switch between different language string resource folders in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018805/how-to-pragmatically-switch-between-different-language-string-resource-folders-i/20020644#20020644)